# designer crash visual studio 2010 for windows phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm having all kinds of problems getting Visual Studio 2010 to work with the Windows Phone 7 templates.  All I have is a default portrait view added to the project, and the designer gives me the following error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Phone, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=24eec0d8c86cda1e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

followed by a bunch of crap that doesn't seem too helpful.  If I rebuild the project and refresh the designer, it momentarily appears correctly (less than a second), and then Visual Studio crashes and tries to restart.

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Shot in the dark: run Visual Studio as administrator.

Comment: changed the launch settings to run as administrator... same problem.  Its weird, because sometimes the designer loads just fine, but if I switch between pages, it will throw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sounds like the install didn't go well.  Verify that this reference assembly is located where it is supposed to be, the default install location is c:\program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework\silverlight\v4.0\profile\windowsphone.  Randomly retrying to reinstall might pay off but do check your machine health first, this doesn't go wrong very often.  Ask questions about that at superuser.com

Comment: reinstall seems to do the trick.  It looks like my version was already quite out of date.